# Is there a more efficient method of reading XML fields with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

In the future I will read 200,000 xml files and from each file capture some information. I need to find a way to get as quickly as possible ...

**My XML:**

```
<note>
    <fields>
       <name>john</name>
       <lastname>doe</lastname>
    </fields>
    <info>
        <chNFe>VALUE</chNFe>
    </info>
</note>
```

I want to get `chNFe` node's value

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\myxml.xml");
Regex.Replace(xml, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var matchingElements = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "chNFe");
string chave = matchingElements.First().Value;

Console.WriteLine("Chave: " + chave);
```

Is there a more efficient method of reading XML fields with LINQ?

Comment: Um, your sample XML doesn't include `chNFe`, making it hard to see how it's relevant. (It's also longer than is useful - please cut everything down to a [mcve].) Do you know the namespace that the element will be in? If so, you can juset use `Descendants(XName)`, constructing the `XName` from an `XNamespace` and a `string`.

Comment: Node `chNFe` doesn't exist in your sample XML. Is that the correct node you're looking for?

Comment: Also, are you looking for execution time efficiency? Clean code? Low space requirements? Is it particularly inefficient as it is? If so, how are you measuring that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I corrected the question

Comment: What is the `Regex.Replace()` for? If you have to do that 200,000 times then better make sure to pre-compile the pattern.

Comment: because some xml files come with invalid characters , and causes errors

Comment: @BrunoHenri: If your XML contains non-UTF-8 characters, there are better options than simply stripping them out. For example, create a subclass of `XmlTextReader` and overwrite the default encoder to UTF-16, and pass an instance of that into `XDocument.Load`.

Comment: The fastest way to parse XML is XmlReader. In your case, once found the first desired item, you can stop parsing and go to the next file. Thus, the xml-file will not be read entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for the descendant node via `XName` will be slightly faster:

```
var chave = doc.Descendants("chNFe").First().Value;
```

**Update**: Grabbing elements directly is a tiny bit faster still:

```
var chave = doc.Root.Element("info").Element("chNFe").Value;
```

However, the vast majority of the time your program spends will be in reading from the disk and parsing the XML documents, so you're probably not going to get noticeable gains as long as you're using LINQ to XML.

[Here's](http://share.linqpad.net/6qale6.linq) my benchmark code. And here are the results:

[image]

Comment: I'd be curious to see your results for the `doc.Root.Element("info").Element("chNFe").Value;` version? I expect it to be similar to your `.Descendants("chNFe")`.

Comment: presented the following error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
Additional information: The sequence contains no elements

Comment: @BrunoHenri: Are you using the actual input that you gave in the OP? I'm guessing you've got namespaces or something that you've stripped out of the example? Those will need to be added into the Descendants search.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ: That looks like it's even faster. I updated the answer. Feel free to take my benchmark LINQPad script and tweak it to try other approaches too.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is pretty darn fast, but drilling down through the tree explicitly seems to be even faster.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var chave = doc.Root.Element("info").Element("chNFe").Value;
```

using an XPath query might be a way to maintain about the same performance but simplify your code:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var chave = doc.XPathSelectElement("/note/info/chNFe").Value;
```

Also, you probably don't have to read the file content separately from parsing it; use `XDocument.Load` to supply a path to a file and let it do the reading.

My test results (1,000,000 runs of each, average time):

```
1. LINQ -> Descendants() = 0.000019ms
2. XPath                 = 0.000024ms
3. LINQ -> Element()     = 0.000004ms
```

Comment: That's weird. On my machine, this approach seems to take 7x longer. I wonder what the difference is.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: that is curious. I used LINQPad, C#, a `Stopwatch`, averaged a few runs of a million runs each. I was getting numbers like `0.000104 ms` for the LINQ version and `0.000059 ms` for the XPath version.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to say without seeing the specific code you used. Have you tried looking at the benchmark LINQPad file I linked from my answer, to see if you get the same results from that?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Your test suite is basically a fancier version of what I hacked together except I wasn't doing any dry runs. That could certainly mean there are some outliers in my data.

Comment: XPath, of course, is the slowest. However, it can be accelerated using the `XPathNavigator` and the compiled XPath expression.